# Content pushed down in IE 7

Tags: css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

My site looks good in both Firefox, IE 8, and chrome. However in IE 7 the middle content get pushed down. 
I don't understand why, can anyone advise me how to fix this? I tried to float both left and right but it didn't work.

Any help appreciated. Thank you in advance!

---

Hi all, I have solved the issue by adding in some tables. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it has something to do with doctype declarations? Here's a tutorial on them:

[Right here](http://htmldog.com/guides/htmladvanced/declarations/)

You might want to read it and give it a try. Perhaps that could solve your problem.

It could also be a CSS compatibility problem. Take a look at this web page:

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It shows which CSS elements are compatible with IE 7 and other versions. If you used an element which is incompatible with IE 7, it might be what is causing you trouble.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In your style.css, the "border-spacing" command in the "table" element is not compatible with IE 7 according to the document I linked you to. How about removing that line and trying again? Maybe it could make things work for you.

Comment: Hi AndresR, thanks a lot for the suggestion. I have read through , tried few and tried your suggestion as well but it didn't work. :( Thanks for your answer though :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the `margin-left:210px` on a few of your DIVs is pushing the content down. Try assigning the following class in your stylesheet:

```
.head-nav,
.banner,
.sponsorslogo,
.wp_bannerize_sponsors,
#main{
float:left;
}
```

If that fixes it, it might be worth to rethink the layout of your design slightly where you place the above mentioned elements in a DIV that has a `margin-left:210px` and then `float:left` the `#header` to the left and place it above the new DIV.

Alternatively, if you want a quick fix that only targets the IE7 glitch you can always include the above style in an IE7 only stylesheet:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your answer. I have tried your solution but it didn't work. I removed the margin-left:210px, the middle content will overlap with left sidebar in FF. I then placed a new DIV into left hand menu and another div into right hand menu to test out. It didn't work either. :(

Comment: Can you throw a copy of your css and html up on jsfiddle.net ? That way I can have a live version to play with. Cheers.